# C++: Why is the string array converting my string?

Tags: c++

On the line 43 (the function Auto_Padding) for some reason the array makes my string transition.
The string was: 04, it became 00.

I have tried changing the keyword between static and non-static for error prevention, correcting type casting, printing out every variable possible, but I still see no solution

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

string Add_Padding(string val, int padding_amount) {
    string result = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < padding_amount; i++) {
        result += "0";
    }

    return result.append(val);
}

string *Auto_Padding(string val1, string val2) {
    int val1L = val1.length();
    int val2L = val2.length();

    if (val1L > val2L) {
        val2 = Add_Padding(val2, val1L - val2L);
        val1.insert(0, "0");
        val2.insert(0, "0");

        static string to_return[3] = {val1, val2, to_string(val1L)};
        return to_return;
    }
    else if (val1L < val2L) {
        val1 = Add_Padding(val1, val2L - val1L);
        val1.insert(0, "0");
        val2.insert(0, "0");

        static string to_return[3] = {val1, val2, to_string(val2L)};
        return to_return;
    }
    else {
        val1.insert(0, "0");
        val2.insert(0, "0");

        static string to_return[3] = {val1, val2, to_string(val1L)};
        // CONVERTS 04 to 00?
        return to_return;
    }
}

string Arithmetic_Add(string tempVal1, string tempVal2) {
    string *values = Auto_Padding(tempVal1, tempVal2);
    string val1 = values[0];
    string val2 = values[1];
    
    int loop_amount = stoi(values[2]);
    int carry = 0;
    int currentResult;
    int tempVar;

    string result = "";

    for (int i = loop_amount; -1 < i; i--) {
        currentResult = carry + (val1[i] - '0') + (val2[i] - '0');

        if (currentResult > 9) {
            carry = floor(currentResult / 10);
            tempVar = currentResult % 10;
            result.insert(0, to_string(tempVar));
        }
        else {
            carry = 0;
            result.insert(0, to_string(currentResult));
        }
    }

    if (result[0] == '0') {
        result.erase(0, 1);
    }

    return result;
}

string Arithmetic_Multiply(string val1, string val2) {
    int loop_amount = stoi(val2);
    string val = "0";

    for (int i = 0; i < loop_amount; i++) {
        val = Arithmetic_Add(val, val1);
    }

    return val2;
}

int main() {
    cout << Arithmetic_Multiply("4", "5"); //outputs 5, not 20
    cout << endl;
    cout << flush;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `static` local variable is only initialized once, when execution passes over its definition for the first time. Thus, `static string to_return[3] = {val1, val2, to_string(val1L)};` is initialized on the first call to `Auto_Padding` and is never changed afterwards. Subsequent calls all return values computed by that first call; `to_return` is never updated.

Comment: Before you ask, just dropping `static` won't work either; this way, you'd be returning a pointer to a local variable. That variable is destroyed when the function returns, and the pointer becomes dangling before the caller has a chance to look at it. You probably want to return the three strings by value, e.g. via `std::array<std::string, 3>` or via a `std::tuple` of three strings, or your own named struct.

Comment: From "Arithmetic_Multiply" method, you're returning "val2" which is the second parameter you received in this method. That's why it's returning 5. If you call "Arithmetic_Multiply("4", "6"), the output of your code will be 6